# Cannot activate a flow in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm having trouble to activate my recently created flow in Salesforce. I'm working with the last API version.

[image]

There's no ACTIVATE button available even after saving the flow with no errors. I've debugged the thing and it's working fine, which is even more weird.

I couldn't be able to activate the flow even from SETUP ---> FLOWS cause there's not activation button beside the flow's name as expected.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_activate.htm

Comment: Not a lot of a help ... Been there, done that ... thanks anyways